# Deriving the log-likelihood of an 'complicated' distribution

Tags: likelihood

In 'Likelihood-based inference with singular information matrix' (Rotnitzky) an example is given as follows:

> Suppose that $Y$ is normally distributed with mean $\beta$ and variance $\sigma^2$. There are available for study $n$ independent individuals but for each there is the possibility that the value of $Y$ cannot be observed. If the probability of not being able to observe $Y$ is assumed independent of the unobserved value the analysis proceeds with just the fully observed
>   individuals. Suppose, however, that conditionally on $Y= y$ the probability of observing $y$ has the form
>   $$\mathcal{P}_c(y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1) = \exp\left\{H\left(\alpha_0+\alpha_1\dfrac{y-\beta}{\sigma}\right)\right\}$$
>   where $(\alpha_0, \alpha_1)$ are unknown parameters and $H(\cdot)$ is a known function assumed to have its first three derivatives at $\alpha_0$ non-zero. 
>   Interest may lie in small values of $\alpha_1$ and in particular in testing the null hypothesis $\alpha_1=0$.
>
> We thus consider two random variables $(R,Y)$, where $R$ is binary, taking values 0 and 1. The value of $Y$ is observed if and only if $R=1$. The contribution of one individual to the log-likelihood is thus
>   $$-r\log \sigma - r \frac{(y-\beta)^2}{(2\sigma)^2} + rH\left(\alpha_0+\alpha_1 \dfrac{y-\beta}{\sigma}\right) + (1-r)\log Q_c(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$$
>
> where
>   $$Q_C(\alpha_0,\alpha_1) = E\{1-\mathcal{P}_c(Y;\alpha_0,\alpha_1)\}$$
>   is the marginal probability that $Y$ is not observed. For $n$ individuals the log-likelihood $L_n(\beta,\sigma, \alpha_0, \alpha_1)$ is the sum of $n$ such terms.

But I don't get how this log-likelihood was derived. I guess I would need something like $f_{Y,R}(y,r) = f_{Y|R}(y|r) \cdot f_R(r)$ but how does this work?

Also I know how
$$f_R(r) = \left(\exp\left\{H\left(\alpha_0+\alpha_1\dfrac{y-\beta}{\sigma}\right) \right\}\right)^r \cdot \left(1-\exp\left\{H\left(\alpha_0+\alpha_1\dfrac{y-\beta}{\sigma}\right)\right\}\right)^{1-r}$$
But then the log-likelihood would be 
$$r\cdot \left\{H\left(\alpha_0+\alpha_1\dfrac{y-\beta}{\sigma}\right)\right\}+(1-r) \cdot \log\left(1-\exp\left\{H\left(\alpha_0+\alpha_1\dfrac{y-\beta}{\sigma}\right)\right\}\right) $$

Why is $Q_c$ the expected value of $1-\mathcal{P}_c$?

Comment: I upvoted to cancel the downvote. I'm not sure why it was downvoted in the first place, this seems like a perfectly legitimate question. You even showed your own attempt to construct a Likelihood function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, $Y$ is independent of $R$ but not vice versa. So it makes more sense to decompose the distribution as $p(Y,R) = p(R \mid Y) p(Y).$ However, keep in mind that the Likelihood is defined to be the probability of the *observed* data, given the model parameters. If $R=0$ then $Y$ is not observed. Therefore the likelihood of an observation for which $R=0$ would be the marginal probability of $R=0$. That is, for a single observation for which $R=0$,

$$
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}(Y,R=0) &= p(R=0) \\ &= \int p(R=0 \mid y) p(y) dy \\
&= \int \{ 1 - \mathcal{P}_c(y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1)\} p (y) dy \\
&= E\{1 - \mathcal{P}_c(y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1)\}.
\end{split}
$$
The key point here is that if $R=0$ then $Y$ is unobserved, so we're taking the probability of only the observed variable here, namely $p(R)$. In cases where $R=1$ we observe both $R$ and $Y$ so the likelihood contribution of this data point becomes $$ \mathcal{L}(Y, R=1) = p(Y,R=1) = p(Y) p(R=1 \mid Y) =  \mathcal{N}(Y \mid \beta, \sigma^2) \mathcal{P}_c(Y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1).$$
So to put it generally, the log likelihood for a single observation becomes
$$
\begin{split}
\log \mathcal{L}(Y,R) &= R \log p(Y,R) + (1-R) p(R) \\
&= R \{ \log \mathcal{N}(Y \mid \beta, \sigma^2) + \log \mathcal{P}_c(Y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1) \} + (1-R)E\{1 - \mathcal{P}_c(y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1)\}.
\end{split}
$$

EDIT: As Alecos Papadopoulos correctly pointed out, my first sentence is mistaken. What I should say is that it's more *convenient* to use my decomposition, but you can certainly decompose it in the other direction if you want. I don't think that this undermines the rest of my steps.

Comment: "$Y $ is indepenednt of $R$ but not vice versa". This is wrong, pairwise stochastic independence is reciprocal. $R$ is independent of $Y$ because the event "$Y$ has/has not been observed" is not part of the support of the distrinbution of $Y$. It is only with respect to these events that $R$ is not independent.

Comment: They are not pairwise independent. $R$ is *defined* to be the label of the event "$Y$ has/has not been observed", which is given by the distribution $p(R) = \mathcal{P}_c(Y)^R (1 - \mathcal{P}_c(Y)^{1-R}).$ You're right that the event of "$Y$ has/has not been observed" (i.e. $R$) is not in the support of $p(Y)$, but that tells us that $Y$ is independent of $R$, not vice versa. The converse statement is not true; $Y$ is very much part of the support of the distribution of the event of whether we observed $Y$ (i.e. the distribution of $R$).

Comment: Well, whether $Y$ has been observed or not does not affect whether it has been realized or not. So the probabilities $P(Y\leq y \mid R=0)$ and $P(R=0\mid Y\leq y)$ are well defined. Applying the well known relation we then have

$$P(Y\leq y \mid R=0) \cdot P(R=0) = P(R=0\mid Y\leq y)\cdot P(Y\leq y)$$

$Y$ is independent of $R$, so $P(Y\leq y \mid R=0) = P(Y\leq y)$, which leads us to $P(R=0) = P(R=0\mid Y\leq y)$, which tells us that $R$ is indpendent of $Y$ (after doing the same exercise for $R=1$ of course). Am I missing something here?

Comment: I believe the mistake would be in saying that $P(Y \le y \mid R=1) = P(Y \le y)$. Suppose, hypothetically, that $P(R \mid Y) \equiv \mathcal{P}_c(Y) = \delta(Y-Z)$. That means that if we observed $Y$ then $Y$ is *necessarily* equal to $Z$. So even though the process in which $Y$ is drawn happens before (and thus is independent of) it is observed, whether or not we observed it gives us a hint as to what it was, so the conditional $p(Y \mid R) \ne P(Y)$. Of course that means that I was mistaken in my first sentence, so thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: "...whether or not we observed it gives us a hint as to what it was". Well, Remember the classic prank: "Can you tel me what time it is? - Yes (then silence)", contrasted to "Can you tel me what time it is? - Yes, it is 12:15"... In our case we are asking "suppose that $Y$ has been observed. What are the probabilities that $Y$ took a value no greater than $y$?" There is no information about the value of $Y$ in the assertion that we have observed it.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused now. How do you square that with my hypothetical scenario, $P(R=1 \mid Y) = \delta(Y-Z)$? (Sorry I mistyped it before.) If  $Y$ was *observed*, then $Y$ couldn't possibly have been anything but $Z$, so in this case, the act of it having been observed directly *tells* us what it must have been. So if $Z>y$, for example, then $P(Y \le y \mid R=1) = 0 \ne P(Y \le y).$

Comment: The point I am trying to make is that two rv's are either independent or not. It is not possible that "the one is independent from the other, but the other is not independent from the former". In your post what you asserted is that "$R$ is not independent from $Y$". The attempt to verbaly transalte this creates confusion. To say "assume $Y$ is no greater than $y$" makes us think that we must have observed $Y$. But this is not the case. Perhaps it could be better phrased "If $Y$ had been realized as no greater than $y$, what would be the probability that it would have been observed?"

Comment: Well yes, I agree with you. My first sentence was mistaken, and two rv's are independent or they're not. However I think the resolution to my mistake is to say that $Y$ is conditionally dependent on $R$, which is proven by the fact that $R$ is conditionally dependent on $Y$. The answer to "If $Y \le y$ what would be the probability that it gets observed?" is different from the answer to "if $Y > y$ what would be the probability that it gets observed?", which tells us that $R$ is conditionally dependent on $Y$. I'm not sure where you stand on that.

Comment: Why the answer would be different? In either case the value of Y does not affect the probabilities of observing it... we are not told that some values are harder to observe than others

Comment: Yes, in fact we are *explicitly* told that some values are harder to observe than others. The problem states, "Suppose, however, that conditionally on $Y=y$ the probability of observing $y$ has the form $\mathcal{P}_c(y; \alpha_0, \alpha_1) = \exp\{H(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \frac{y-\beta}{\sigma})\}$".